# R : Problems in creating a seq(0,9) in a loop

Tags: r, seq

I am trying to write a function in R but I'm struggling with a sequence problem:

```
vincent <- function(v,n, val_min){
  # v = vector to vincentize n = number of bin +1 
  mean_vct <- array(0, n) # n = nb de bins; crée un vecteur de 5 zéros si n = 5
  vsort <- sort(v)
  vsort <- sort(subset(vsort, vsort>= val_min))
  for (j in seq(1,n) ){
    mean_vct[j] <- (val_inf(j,vsort,n) + val_inter(j,vsort,n) + val_sup(j,vsort,n))
    mean_vct[j] <- mean_vct[j]/(length(vsort)/(n))
   }
  return (mean_vct)
}
```

When applying this code with a print of the sequence, I get : 
   `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0` instead of `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`
And I need this sequence to begin with 0 because I'm converting a code from Python to R.

Thanks

Edit : An example for applying this function :

```
RT <- 1:100
vincent(RT, 10, 0)
```

Comment: R indexing starts a 1, not at 0. It is different from Python.

Comment: basically what you are doing in your function is just returning `0:9`. What's your wanted output? What do you try to achieve?

Comment: Yes I know that and I thought I would be able to get over it by creating a sequence that starts from 0, Is there no way to use a loop with a sequence starting at 0 ?

Comment: Please add your function call like vincent(1:3, 3) so we can reproduce your sample.

Comment: seq(0, 9) returns: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
which is the same as 0:9

Comment: What are you trying to do? (Note that you initialize `mean_vct` with length `n` but then proceed to fill it with 10 entries - if `n` is 5, this will break.)

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel I made this for debugging purpose, my goal-oriented loop is now in the question
The code basically compute bins for my data and the mean for each bin, and the function of val_inf, val_sup and val_inter are coded as if j would start with 0.

Comment: Neither the loop nor the sequence are the problem here - it's the indexing. `mean_vct[j]` requires `j` to be an integer >0.

Comment: I put an example in the question
@StephanKolassa I answered to this question on the comment below, and for the 10 entries yes, I first used 'n' but I tried with aa number for debugging purpose again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with your code.

```
vincent <- function(v,n){
  # v = vector to vincentize n = number of bin
  mean_vct <- array(0, n)
  vsort <- sort(v) #Tri dans l'ordre les TR
  for (j in seq(0,9)){ #pour chaque bin
    mean_vct[j] <- j
  }
  return (mean_vct)
}
```

**for (j in seq(0, 9))**

1. You should go to n and not until 9, using another example will crash your loop
2. There are easier ways to go from 0 to n -> `0:n` creates a sequence just like seq(0,9) (you are probably used to the range method in python)

**mean_vct[j] <- j**

This will not work because R starts indexing at one.

You have several options:

1. Loop from 1:n instead of 0:(n-1) and incase you need j for your computations use (j-1) in your computations
2. Loop from 0:(n-1) and use mean_vct[j+1]

Since I started writing this answer you changed your code, but this should still explain your problem.

Answer (score 2):

It's worth noting that `array` is really for multidimensional arrays. You could initiate `mean_vct` using `mean_vct <- numeric(9)`.

The main issue is that you can't assign to `mean_vct[0]`, because indexing of vectors always starts at 1. The reason that `mean_vct[10]` contains 0 is that you initiated it with 0. You could use character indexing if you really want to refer to your vector by indexes that start at 0 but it may be confusing.

Finally, this sort of thing is usually done much better with vectorised code in R. e.g.

```
mean_vct <- 0:9
```

and if desired:

```
names(mean_vct) <- 0:9
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, from now on I will be aware of the use of vectorised code.